# Zoom into square of labels python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, zooming

I have a square of labels that make a scrabble board. ([link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twd9Q.png))

Code to generate:

```
colors = {"TWS":"red", "DWS":"pink", "TLS":"light green", "DLS":"light blue", "*":"pink"}
self.boardFrame = Frame(self.root, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
self.boardFrame.place(x=50, y=50, width=497, height = 497)
labels = list()
squares = list()
for i in range(16):
    for j in range(16):
        label = self.board[j][i]
        if label in self.extraList:
            entry = Frame(self.boardFrame, bd=1, relief=RAISED)
            entry.place(x=(i*31), y=(j*31), width=31, height=31)
            labels.append(func.Label(entry, text = label,
                                     height = 31, width = 31))
            if label in colors.keys():
                labels[-1].config(bg=colors[label])
            labels[-1].pack()
```

I would like to make it able to zoom in when the user clicks it. I have heard that you could use something like `canvas`. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436810/adding-zooming-in-and-out-with-a-tkinter-canvas-widget-in-python) but I did not understand it particularly. If I had a image for each type of square (which is possible), how could I efficiently resize every label? Something like:

```
def zoom(self, event):
    if math.isclose(event.x, self.x, abs_tol=self.boardWidth/2) and \
       math.isclose(event.y, self.y, abs_tol=self.boardHeight/2):
        self.height += 30
        self.width += 30
        self.x -= event.x
        self.y -= event.y
        self.label.config(height=self.height, width=self.width)
        self.label.place_configure(x = self.x, y = self.y)
```

I'm not sure. Any help would be welcome really. Thanks.

EDIT: When I say zoom, I mean actually zoom in. For example, zooming in 2x will only have 1/4 of the labels visible, and they will each be twice as big.

EDIT: by the way all of the code is in the `tiles.py` in [this github repo](https://github.com/Innoviox/HammerHead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to scale a drawing that is already drawn on `tkinter`'s `Frame` or `Canvas`. But you can implement scaling yourself by multiplying you cells dimensions by scale factor when needed.
Here is some demo code:

```
from tkinter import *

def drawBoard(boardFrame, scale):
   cellSize = 31 * scale

   for i in range(16):
      for j in range(16):
         entry = Frame(boardFrame, bd=1, relief=RAISED)
         entry.place(x=(i*cellSize), y=(j*cellSize), width=cellSize, height=cellSize)

def buttonCallback(event):      
    global scale
    scale = scale + 0.1
    drawBoard(boardFrame, scale)        

scale = 1.0
root = Tk()

boardFrame = Frame(root, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
boardFrame.place(x=50, y=50, width=497, height = 497)

drawBoard(boardFrame, scale)    
root.bind("<Button-1>", buttonCallback)

root.mainloop()
```